# Shemoneh Esreh Torah line for Name

Tags: tefilla, names, shemoneh-esrei, prayer-book

Before Oseh Shalom in the Amidah, my Siddur says, "Here one may say a sentence from the Torah, which starts with the first letter of his first name and finishes with the last letter of his first name. For example, if your name is Benyamin, you may say the sentence "Baruch Adonai Leolam Amen Veamen".

Would somebody be able to tell me a sentence for my first name - Nathaniel : נתנאל?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this list](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20312&st=&pgnum=391), the corresponding verse for the name Netanel would be:

> נחשבתי עם יורדי בור הייתי כגבר אין איל
>
> (תהילים פח-ה)

Comment: Some more here: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A7_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9C_%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A0_%D7%9C

Answer (score 3):

I heard from Rabbi [Dovid Fink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Fink) that you can also say a passuk that has your name. So you could say any possuk featuring someone named Nesanel. From the beginning of Bamidbar: ליששכר נתנאל בן צוער.